# How to authenticate hosts with Ansible?

Tags: ansible

My hosts file

```
[all]
192.168.77.10
192.168.77.11
192.1680.77.12
```

And here is my playbook.yml

```
---
- hosts: all

  tasks:
   - name: Add the Google signing key
     apt_key : url=https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg state=present

   - name: Add the k8s APT repo
     apt_repository: repo='deb http://apt.kubernetes.io/ kubernetes-xenial main' state=present

   - name: Install packages
     apt :
      name: "{{ packages }}"
     vars:
      packages:
       - vim
       - htop
       - tmux
       - docker.io
       - kubelet
       - kubeadm
       - kubectl
       - kubernetes-cni
```

When I run

```
ansible-playbook -i hosts playbook.yml
```

unexpected authentication problem occurs.

```
The authenticity of host '192.168.77.11 (192.168.77.11)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:mgX/oadP2cL6g33u7xzrEblvga9CGfpW13K2YUdeKsE.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? The authenticity of host '192.168.77.10 (192.168.77.10)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:ayWHzp/yquIuQxw7MKGR0+NbtrzHY86Z8PdIPv7r6og.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? fatal: [192.1680.77.12]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: ssh: Could not resolve hostname 192.1680.77.12: Name or service not known\r\n", "unreachable": true}
^C [ERROR]: User interrupted execution
```

I am following the example from DevOps book,I reproduced the original code. MY OS is Ubuntu 18.04.

```
telnet hosts
telnet: could not resolve hosts/telnet: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

VM ls output

```
vagrant@ubuntu-bionic:~$ ls
hosts  playbook.retry  playbook.yml
```

I edited /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg by ading False option.
Anyway it does not work again

```
fatal: [192.1680.77.12]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: ssh: Could not resolve hostname 192.1680.77.12: Name or service not known\r\n", "unreachable": true}
fatal: [192.168.77.10]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: Warning: Permanently added '192.168.77.10' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.\r\nvagrant@192.168.77.10: Permission denied (publickey).\r\n", "unreachable": true}
fatal: [192.168.77.11]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: Warning: Permanently added '192.168.77.11' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.\r\nvagrant@192.168.77.11: Permission denied (publickey).\r\n", "unreachable": true}
    to retry, use: --limit @/home/vagrant/playbook.retry

PLAY RECAP *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
192.168.77.10              : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=1    failed=0   
192.168.77.11              : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=1    failed=0   
192.1680.77.12             : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=1    failed=0
```

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: The error states that there is no such host with ip 192.168.77.10 or at least ansible is unable to connect. Can you check if telnet is working from ansible to the host ?

Comment: is your issue resolved or not ?

Comment: If you still have the new issue it should probably be another question as it is a different problem. One IP address is wrong, it should be 168 not 1680. For the other two the error is that you are not authorized to connect, you need them to trust your public SSH key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several options. One is of course to SSH to the hosts and add them to the known hosts files of your Ansible servers. Another option is to set the environment variable `ANSIBLE_HOST_KEY_CHECKING` to false. A third option is to use the ansible.cfg config file:

```
[defaults]
host_key_checking = False
```

See [the official documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_getting_started.html#host-key-checking).